# How to get partials to load once registerPartial have completed

Tags: express, handlebars.js

So decided to try handlebars for templating my node application (OK, no, decided to use keystone.js for something, and Handlebars seemed nicer than jade, what can I say, HTML is my dirty secret).

Built my webpage, and in the ned I want to load a number of javascripts for jquery, angular bootstrap and some other bits and pieces. All seems to work on Chrome, but the first time you access the server, you get error 500 saying that partial basejs could not be found, and the below error message on the server.

```
Error: The partial basejs could not be found
    at Object.invokePartial (/Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/constructmind_http/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/runtime.js:266:11)
```

basejs is just the first hook for about four scripts. The file itself looks as follows:

```
{{!--
    //- jQuery 1.11.3 is included by default, and required by both Bootstrap
    //- and the KeystoneJS Content Editor. If you are not targeting IE8,
    //- you can upgrade to 2.1.4 (also bundled) for better performance.
--}}
<script src="/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
{{!--
    //- Customise which Bootstrap javascript files are served by including
    //- them specifically here, instead of bootstrap-3.3.5.min.js
--}}
<script src="/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-3.3.5.min.js"></script>
```

It is loaded by a helper function called in the beginning of the template file, the helper file just takes every file in a directory and register them as handlebars partials using hbs.registerPartial

```
_helpers.loadJS = function(user, options){
    var partialsDir = __dirname + '/../loadjs';

    var filenames = fs.readdirSync(partialsDir);
    filenames.forEach(function (filename) {
        var matches = /^([^.]+).hbs$/.exec(filename);
        if (!matches) {
            return;
        }
        var name = matches[1];
        var template = fs.readFileSync(partialsDir + '/' + filename, 'utf8');
        hbs.registerPartial(name, template);

    });


}
```

In the beginning of my layout file I call the helper:

```
{{!-- Lets load our pariatls for scripts--}}
{{{loadJS}}}
```

Lastly, in the very end of the file, I then call each partial:

```
{{> basejs }}
{{> setscreen }}
{{> angular_load }}
{{> google_ga }}
```

I think all that is happening is that basejs is called before loadJS have completed, but how do I get handlebar to either
1.  run the helper then call the partials
2.  Get the layout template to check that loadJS have completed and if not wait until it has

Answer (score 2):

OK, I don't think it is possible to do it this way, or at least not in a nice way (basically, the development team behind handlebars.js REALLY want to keep handlebars async, which is all fine).

However, what I did not realise is that the helpers are registered on server lever, so if you instead of registering it as a helper you just add it as a function in the module and call it, it will register them as the server start.

This is the code that solved it in my case

```
module.exports = function () {
    var loadJS = function(user, options){
        var partialsDir = __dirname + '/../loadjs';
        var filenames = fs.readdirSync(partialsDir);

        filenames.forEach(function (filename) {
            var matches = /^([^.]+).hbs$/.exec(filename);
            if (!matches) {
                return;
            }
            var name = matches[1];
            var template = fs.readFileSync(partialsDir + '/' + filename, 'utf8');
            hbs.registerPartial(name, template);
        });



    }
    loadJS();
```

Technically it does not need to be a function as it is called just after its created, but I like to keep it that way:)

For the discussion on async in handlebars.js 
https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/717